# Show div on hover, of current only (one at a time, not all at once)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently using the below:

**angular JS:**

```
$scope.showPopover = function() {
  $scope.popoverIsVisible = true; 
};

$scope.hidePopover = function () {
  $scope.popoverIsVisible = false;
};
```

**Mark-Up:**

```
<span class="margin-top-10 display-block">{{doc.pcpText}}
  <span class="bCert" ng-mouseover="showPopover()"
        ng-mouseleave="hidePopover()">Board Certified: 
    <img src="https://www.verycool.website.com/core/images/questionmark.png"
         class="question_mark"> 
    <span class="yes">Yes</span>
  </span>
  <span class="VerC">Verify Certification
  </span>
</span>
<span class="boxShow" ng-show="popoverIsVisible">
  Which board(s) certifies the provider. This information is blah blah blah 
  12 months.
</span>
```

- The problem with it; is it shows the tool tips/hovers all at once when
  you hover over it. **I only want to instantiate this over the current
  item being hovered, so one at a time,** instead of all at once, any suggestions?
  My mark-up above is dynamically included down the page; so I don't want to hover over the first, and have all the below 'tooltip boxes' show, as it is currently. I just want to show the hover of the current one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$scope.showPopover = function() {
  this.popoverIsVisible = true; 
};

$scope.hidePopover = function () {
  this.popoverIsVisible = false;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Define a variable that value set to false if tooltip was displayed once.
In example - `tooltipIsNotDisplayed`

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('example', example)
  .directive('popover', popover);

function example() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'example.directive.html'
  }
}

function popover() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function popover($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
      $scope.popoverMessage = $attrs.popoverMessage;
      $elem.addClass('popover');
      $elem.append('<div class="popover-message">' + $scope.popoverMessage + '</div>');
    }
  }
}

angular.bootstrap(
  document.getElementById('root'), ['app']
);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.popover .popover-message {
  display: none;
}
.popover:hover .popover-message {  
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="example.directive.html">
     <span popover popover-message="popover message">
        text
     </span>
     <span popover popover-message="other popover message">
        other text
     </span>
  </script>
  <example></example>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it to be continuous... Not only work during the first hover? My problem is I have multiple of these tooltips, and I don't want them each to 'show' on the hover of the first one.

Comment: I changed my code. Try to use `popover` directive. Styles you may make as you want.

Answer (score -1):

Make the `popoverIsVisible` variable a hash:

```
$scope.popoverIsVisible = {};

$scope.showPopover = function(id) {
  $scope.popoverIsVisible[id] = true; 
};

$scope.hidePopover = function (id) {
  $scope.popoverIsVisible[id] = false;
};
```

In the template use it:

```
 <span class="bCert" ng-mouseover="showPopover('info1')"
       ng-mouseleave="hidePopover('info1)">Board Certified: 
    <img src="https://www.verycool.website.com/core/images/questionmark.png"
         class="question_mark"> 
    <span class="yes">Yes</span>
 </span>
 <span class="boxShow" ng-show="popoverIsVisible.info1">
  Which board(s) certifies the provider. This information is blah blah blah 12 months.
</span>

 <span class="bCert" ng-mouseover="showPopover('otherInfo')"
       ng-mouseleave="hidePopover('otherInfo')">Other content
 </span>
 <span class="boxShow" ng-show="popoverIsVisible.otherInfo">
  Other  blah blah blah 12 months.
</span>
```